# Using Twitter-Bootstrap in Python 3.3 Server File

Tags: python, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently in the proccess of editing the html in the Python 3.3 http server code. I am doing this so I can access my media files from anywhere in my LAN. The default interface is quite boring, so I wanted to spruce it up a bit with Twitter Bootstrap buttons. The below code is from my edited server.py file, starting on line 740 (please excuse the lack of editing or elegance):

```
title = 'Media Listing on Computer'
    r.append('<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" '
             '"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">')
    r.append('<html>\n<head>')
    r.append('<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" '
             'content="text/html; charset=%s">' % enc)
    r.append('<title>%s</title>\n<link href="file:///C:/Server/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">\n<style type="text/css">a:link {color:grey; text-decoration: none;}</style>\n</head>' % title)
    r.append('<body>\n<FONT FACE="arial" COLOR="grey">\n<h1>%s</h1>' % title)
    #<body style="background-color:#B4F200;>
    #<FONT FACE="courier" COLOR="grey">
    r.append('<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">')
    for name in list:
        fullname = os.path.join(path, name)
        displayname = linkname = name
        # Append / for directories or @ for symbolic links
        if os.path.isdir(fullname):
            displayname = name 
            linkname = name + "/"
        if os.path.islink(fullname):
            displayname = name + "@"
            # Note: a link to a directory displays with @ and links with /
        r.append('<li class="active"><a href="%s">%s</a></li>'
                % (urllib.parse.quote(linkname), html.escape(displayname)))
    r.append('</ul>\n</body>\n</html>\n')
    encoded = '\n'.join(r).encode(enc)
    f = io.BytesIO()
    f.write(encoded)
    f.seek(0)
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html; charset=%s" % enc)
    self.send_header("Content-Length", str(len(encoded)))
    self.end_headers()
    return f
```

This generates a page with the following html:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=mbcs">
<title>Media Listing on Computer</title>
<link href="file:///C:/Server/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">a:link {color:grey; text-decoration: none;}</style>
</head>
<body>
<FONT FACE="arial" COLOR="grey">
<h1>Media Listing on Computer</h1>
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
<li class="active"><a href="FRAPS/">FRAPS</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="iTunes/">iTunes</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="Misc%20videos/">Misc videos</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="Movies/">Movies</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="TV/">TV</a></li>
</ul>
</FONT>
</body>
</html>
```

Now when I open the html in a web browser it works fine, in that it loads the Twitter Bootstrap UI, however, when I run the python server, the UI doesn't load. I would really like to know how I can fix this, so if someone could give me a hand in sorting this out, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Does your browser know you are using the correct stylesheet?  Maybe try using a relative path for bootstrap instead of an absolute `file:///C:/Server/bootstrap.css`?</s>

**UPDATE** (from comments)

You placed bootstrap in a directory outside of the server root directory, so your browser wasn't able to access the css and render it.  Move bootstrap into the server directory (e.g. `C:\Server\lib\http\bootstrap\`) and update the stylesheet path accordingly (e.g. `<link href="/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">`)

Comment: Where is the root of the server located?  Is it at `C:\Server`?

Comment: Well because I didn't want to screw up the original files, I created a duplicate of the Python33 directory. The root directory is  `C:\Server\lib\http`.

Comment: Move bootstrap somewhere inside the `http` folder and update the stylesheet path accordingly.  The server can't access files outside its directory.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did, but unfortunately it didn't work. Thanks all the same.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Well I believe the problem resided in the way Python servers are made, in that the server.py file mightn't have been the root folder. Instead I just used a web link to source the bootstrap.css file. Thanks all the same.